# Django update view only seems to work with regex urls

Tags: django

I am getting my hands dirty with Django and have a simple use case in which i have to create a function based view for updating a Model. Below is my function based view function:

```
def update_post(request, id=None):
    obj = get_object_or_404(PostModel, id=id)
    form = PostModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        print(f"The object that i am going to save is {form.cleaned_data}")
        obj.save()
        messages.success(request, f"Updated object with id {id}")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(f"/blog/read/{id}")
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "blog/update-post.html", context)
```

Below is my update-post.html:

```
<html>
<form method="POST" action="."> {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Change">
</form>

</html>
```

And this is my urls.py file :

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import list_posts, read_post, create_post, update_post

app_name = "blog"

urlpatterns = [
    path('posts/', list_posts, name="list"),
    path('read/<int:id>', read_post, name="read"),
    path("create/", create_post, name="create"),
    #url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/edit/$', update_post, name="update")
    path("update/<int:id>", update_post, name="update"),
]
```

The update view only seems to work when i use the above regex url pattern for editing the post .

Otherwise i get the below error message:

[image: Error message]

Can someone please tell me where i am going wrong with this.

Comment: but here you did not include a primary key: your url is `/blog/update`?

Comment: Yes but how do i include the primary key? Where do i need to put it? In the template or view ?

Comment: You write that in the `action=""`, but by using `action="."` you go to the "directory". You should simply omit the `action=""` here.

Comment: Thank you so much. What is the logic here .Should i always as a rule use action="" ?? or there is a use case for action="." too ?

Comment: well `"."` means that if the path is `/foo/bar`, it will point to `/foo`, that might, depending on how you implement your webserver, have a use case, but I think based on the way you write your `urls.py`, likely not *here*.

Comment: Just one additional request. Based on my urls.py why does it work then for the regex path that i used(commented out in the code above). Even if i use action="." it works like normal . Based on your explanation above i am trying to connect the dots.

Comment: Django has nothing to do with the `"."`. This is just how HTML resolves the paths. Django will not "fill in" a URL. It is simply the browser that will perform URL resolution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help in this . Really appreciate it.